# Three JS LineBasicMaterial how to draw simple fat line in 3D axis?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

lineMat = new THREE.**LineBasicMaterial**({color, linewidth: 5});

**doesn't work.**

I need a simple method for 3D (rotating scene):
drawLine(measurement1, measurement2, color) with linewidth more then 1px

I know about Windows & Angle. I searched & try to solve this problem a few days (most of the found methods not worked or work only in 2D or have problems inside)

Answer (score 3):

It does not work since WebGL line primitives are always rendered as 1px wide lines. However, `three.js` provide the possibility to render so called wide or fat lines based on triangles. So using the classes `LineGeometry`, `LineMaterial` and `Line2` should solve your issue.

Official example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat

`three.js R107`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this method (Line2) but unsuccessful.
I already have done it by THREE.MeshLine https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine

Comment: What do you mean with "unsuccessful"? The official example obviously works fine.

Comment: I had errors & problems with implementing it from here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_lines_fat.html. Maybe it will be more useful if it was a part of Three (like THREE.FatLine ). Sorry I need an only simple method for two points.

Answer (score 2):

[Thanks to @Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013918/threejs-linebasicmaterial-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-3d)

https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { MeshLine, MeshLineMaterial} from 'three.meshline';
```

```
  drawLine(measurement1, measurement2, color) {
    const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(
      new THREE.Vector3( measurement1.X,  measurement1.Y,  measurement1.Z ),
      new THREE.Vector3( measurement2.X,  measurement2.Y,  measurement2.Z )
    );
    const line = new MeshLine();
    line.setGeometry( geometry );
    const material = new MeshLineMaterial({color});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( line.geometry, material );
    this.scene.add( mesh );
}
```

Comment: BTW: The mesh line implementation from the `three.js` repository is actually more performant than `THREE.MeshLine` since instanced rendering is used.