# Adding thickness to lines in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, draw, codesandbox

This is my [demo](https://m1vin.csb.app/), i want to add **linewidth** to give more **thickness** to my quad.

I have looked to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509888/three-js-linebasicmaterial-how-to-draw-simple-fat-line-in-3d-axis) and i have tried to understand how i can use **LineMaterial** and **Line2**.

They seem not working in the demo.

This is the relevant code

```
   function QuadGeometry(w, h) {
      let pts = [
        [0.5, 0.5],
        [-0.5, 0.5],
        [-0.5, -0.5],
        [0.5, -0.5]
      ].map((p) => {
        return new THREE.Vector2(p[0], p[1]);
      });
      let g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pts);
      g.setIndex([0, 1, 2, 3, 0]);
      g.scale(w, h, 1);

      return g;
    }

    let g = QuadGeometry(
      THREE.MathUtils.randInt(15, 30),
      THREE.MathUtils.randInt(15, 30)
    );
    let m = new LineMaterial({
      color: "yellow",
      linewidth: 5
    });
    let quad = new Line2(g, m);
```

As you can see the **quad** is not visible with these changes

If i replace with `LineBasicMaterial` and `Line` the **quad** is visible

I have also found it can be a [bug](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14627) but i am very beginner with three.js

Any edit in the [codesandbox](https://m1vin.csb.app/) it would be great to show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an instance of `BufferGeometry` to create the instance of `Line2` which is not supported. You have to use `LineGeometry` instead.

Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/static-forked-68lif?file=/index.html